MOSFET Total Gate charge graph (Qg)
Below is a Vgs -Qg graph of the IXTH88N30P N-channel MOSFET.
Datasheet: https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/240/media-3322045.pdf
As seen in the graph, this curve is given for Vds = 150 V, Id = 44 A and Ig = 10 mA.
What approach should I follow for different Vds, Id and Ig values ​​so that I can approximate Qg?
How should I proceed when each of these 3 parameters changes?

Source: https://www.mouser.com.tr/datasheet/2/240/media-3322045.pdf


You should study why the gate charge curve has that shape and behavior. Once that's clear to you, you'll also know what changes with e.g. Vds and Id as they come from mosfet current law, which doesn't change.

TI's Application Report SLUA618A–March 2017–Revised October 2018 is an excellent resource for interpreting the gate charge curve.
The effect of VDS extends the Miller region requiring more gate charge, as shown in Figure 6.

According to equation 8, the Miller plateau moves vertically (not shown on a graph) as the "ON" drain current drain current changes. (ONSEMI's 2N7000/70002 datasheet shows this in Figure 10)


All of the gate current is used to charge \$C_{GS}\$ and \$C_{GD}\$. The slope of the line is the inverse of the capacitance \$C_{iss}=C_{GS}+C_{GD}\$ which changes dramatically.
Using the three regions shown in Figure 6, the capacitance is approximated by the definition:
$$
V_{GS}=\frac{1}{C} Q_G
$$
Taking the derivative shows that:
$$
\frac{dV_{GS}}{dt}=\frac{1}{C} I_G
$$
indicating that \$I_G\$ determines the rate of progress along the gate-charge curve.
Notice that in the Miller region, the capacitance appears nearly infinite. This is because all of the gate charge is flowing through the Miller capacitance allowing \$V_{DS}\$ to fall.

From comment:

I know that if Vds decreases the line will move to left so is there any way to define the location? or an apprixamate line as ı draw is enough for approximation ?

CGD changes significantly as the voltage across it decreases from VGS-VGD through zero the to VGS through the Miller region. Estimating the charge delivered from the gate is challenging because of this. The linked application note uses an average value for CGD. The voltage change is VDSoff. So the charge required for the Miller region is approximately CGDave*VDSoff. So higher VDSoff extends the Miller region.

Considering Figure 7 and Figure 8 in datasheet that ı shared in my question, gfs = 25 S for 10 A of Id. Vth is min = 2.5 in the datasheet. If ı put these into Equation 8 that you shared, does that mean  Vgs,miller = 2.5 V + ( 10 A / 25 S) = 2.9 V  ?  @RussellH

That would be the minimum. The maximum would be based on Vth =5V. So VGS_Miller_max=5.4V. A specific device will have a threshold voltage between 2.5 and 5 volts. Designs should be based on the maximum threshold voltage. Transconductance also increases with temperature, so the Miller voltage could be higher.

Okay ı got it, ı have another question. I estimated and sketch a line for 5.4V miller on the same graph. You can check it above in my question. How to estimate the location of Vds for example for 20V of Vds ? I know that if Vds decreases the line will move to left so is there any way to define the location?  or an apprixamate line as ı draw is enough for approximation ?  @RussellH

CGD changes significantly as the voltage across it decreases from VGS-VGD through zero the to VGS through the Miller region.   Estimating the charge delivered from the gate is challenging because of this. The linked application note uses an average value for CGD.
The voltage change is VDSoff. So the charge required for the Miller region is approximately CGDave*VDSoff. So higher VDSoff extends the Miller region.

So in order to calculate CGDave * VDSoff, first ı need to to calculate the CGDavg which is given in the texas document as 2CGD,spec sqrt(VDS,spec / VDS,off)  isn't it sir ?  and by doing that we find the charge required only for miller region , after miller region is completed the line will increase again with the same slope more or less with the sample line given in the datasheets right ? @RussellH

Essentially yes. Remember that averages aren’t perfect. There is significant variability from device to device with the same part number. Read the Texas Instruments application note to understand the approximations made.@Mhan
